# How do I bind data from the database table to an html control like div or tab?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, datatable

I'm designing one web site. In that web site want to use only html controls for displaying data. I'm fetching some data from the table of my database in the code behind file, the data is stored in the datatable. I want to show that data in the grid format. But i don't want to use any asp.net control like gridview, repeater control etc.

How to do this?

Comment: You changed your tags from `PHP` to `ASP` ?? You really know what you want to ask ?? Vote down.

Comment: @Márcio: Initially i haven't added any technology related tag but after reading one reply to this question, i realized that i should add the tag of the asp.net technology.

Answer (score 3):

ASP.NET Controls get rendered as HTML controls anyway, so by using ASP.NET controls you will only be using HTML controls.

For example an ASP.NET `GridView` is rendered as a HTML `Table` when passed to the client (browser)

If you wish to use only HTML controls to give yourself full control over the styles and attributes, you can use a `Repeater` control with a `table`:

```
<table>
  <asp:repeater id="rep" runat="server">
    <itemtemplate>
       <tr>
          <td><%#eval("ColumnName")%></td>
       </tr>
    </itemtemplate>
  </asp:repeater>
</table>
```

Comment: I think you haven't read my question. I don't want to use asp.net control.

Comment: I know when we use asp.net control then browser render it to the html control. So i want to reduce that control rendering procedure of the browser. For that i want to do it with the html control.

Comment: So this is a performance related question? A repeater doesn't render into any HTML, it simply loops through your ItemTemplate rendering the HTML inside.

Comment: No its not performance related question. I just want to bind the datatable to the html control & it should repeat till the end of the datatable.

Comment: What are your reasons for not using an ASP.NET control to get the results you need?

Comment: Well, use asp.net as it is designed to be used,. not how your delusions want ioiot to be used. THAT SAID: check MVC and the optimized rendering in there. The technologies / approach you use IS clunky (webforms ahve ton of complex issues regarding state) and most people prever MVC. It also is easier to program AND has a better templating appraoch (razor engine).

Answer (score 1):

If you really don't want to use a grid control then just add a placeholder control to the page.

```
<asp:PlaceHolder id="placeHolder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Then dynamically build the grid using the Table and Row objects then once you have constructed the page then add to the placeholder.

```
placeHolder.Controls.Clear();
Table table = new Table()

//.. foreach loop through your data sourde

   TableRow row = new TableRow()
   TableCell cell = new TableCell()

   cell.Text = "your data element";

   row.Cells.Add(cell);
   table.Rows.Add(row);

//.. close loop

placeHolder.Controls.Add(table);
```

This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.tablerow%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) does something similar

I've done this before (can't remember why) but you won't easily be able to page or sort the data. You would need a listview or the like for this. But this will generate the grid you want. I would still recommend looking at ListView, Repeater etc....

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be returning html string, For eg:

Place a div on aspx page,

```
<div id="divHtml" runat="server"  > </div>
```

Code behind,

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

// instantiate a datagrid
DataGrid dg = new DataGrid();
dg.DataSource = dataTable; //your dataTable
dg.DataBind();
dg.RenderControl(htw);
divHtml.InnerHtml = sw.ToString();
```

Here sw will give you the completely rendered html string. Sw can also be added to Response stream like `response.Write(sw.ToString());`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MVC style markup:

```
<%foreach (var row in myData) {%>
    <%=row["somedata"]%>
<%}%>
```

Nothing wrong with that technically. The point being why would you? If you're using webforms, then webcontrols do the above for you in a much much neater fashion. As has been mention you can use a repeater that doesn't add any html but will repeat any html within its templates.